# Can I get admission in Germany for Masters if my university is not there in the Anabin database?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, germany

My college is affiliated with a university recognised by Anabin. But my college on its own is not recognised there. Would it cause any problem with my admission for Masters in Germany?

Comment: https://anabin.kmk.org/filter/faq/studium.html "Über die Zugangsvoraussetzungen für ein Masterstudium bestimmen die Hochschulen." Your best way to get an answer to your question is to contact the university where you want to pursue a Masters. Yes, if your college isn't listed that could mean it will not be accepted. Or that it's not on the list because the list is incomplete (as explicitly stated).